# I need help creating a complex SQL query

Tags: sql, oracle

I need help creating a complex SQL query. Consider the following tables (simplified for example):

**lists**

```
list_id | user_id | list_type
-----------------------------------
1       | 1       | favorite movies
2       | 2       | favorite movies
```

**list_items**

```
list_id | movie_id 
------------------
1       | 1
2       | 1
2       | 2
```

In this example user 1 has added movie 1 to his favorite movies list. User 2 has added movie 1 and movie 2 to his favorite movies list.

I'm trying to output a list of all other movies every user who added movie 1 also added to their favorite movies lists, ordered by frequency. The result should therefore be:

```
movie_id | total_adds
---------------------
2        | 1
```

I'm having issues grasping how I can use COUNT and DISTINCT to generate this output and if I can JOIN somehow to reduce the processing overhead.

Comment: This is not a site where community members do your work (or school work) for you. Along with the problem you must include the code you have up until this point, failing to do that your question will most likely be closed. Please also include a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. See: [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and also read [How do I ask a Good Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: If the problem is exactly as stated: given a movie id (in your example, `1`), find all the "other" movies selected by the users who selected "that" movie, group by these "other" movies, count them and order by decreasing count, then: (1) where would you need `distinct`? I don't see it; (2) why do you need the first table? it seems everything you need is in the second table; (3) the most efficient solution probably uses an `in` condition (a semi-join of the `list_items` table to itself).

Comment: In your actual data, can one user have more than one list? That would explain why you need the first table (and then, indeed, you would need to join the two tables).

Comment: @Igor I'm not asking for the solution, I'm asking for guidance regarding the approach. I don't know where to begin because I'm having trouble grasping this conceptually. I could paste the query I've written so far but it doesn't execute because it's malformed and virtually unusable. Perhaps this isn't the venue but my impression was the spirit of this place was to share knowledge ... it's a bummer it's always assumed people are looking for answers to a school assignment or a job they're not qualified for when really I'm just interested in SQL and have hit a roadblock I'm unable to overcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is another way.  It is a bit more complex, but depending on the data will usually be faster:

```
WITH lists ( list_id, user_id ) AS (
      SELECT 1, 1 FROM dual UNION ALL
      SELECT 2, 2 FROM dual UNION ALL
      SELECT 3, 2 FROM dual UNION ALL
      SELECT 4, 2 FROM dual UNION ALL
      SELECT 5, 3 FROM dual UNION ALL 
      SELECT 6, 3 FROM dual UNION ALL
      SELECT 7, 4 FROM dual UNION ALL
      SELECT 8, 4 FROM dual UNION ALL
      SELECT 9, 4 FROM dual
  ), list_items (list_id, movie_id) AS (
      SELECT 1, 1 FROM dual UNION ALL
      SELECT 2, 1 FROM dual UNION ALL
      SELECT 3, 2 FROM dual UNION ALL
      SELECT 4, 3 FROM dual UNION ALL
      SELECT 5, 2 FROM dual UNION ALL 
      SELECT 6, 3 FROM dual UNION ALL
      SELECT 7, 1 FROM dual UNION ALL
      SELECT 8, 2 FROM dual UNION ALL
      SELECT 9, 9 FROM dual
  ), test_data (user_id, movie_id) AS (
     SELECT user_id, movie_id FROM lists l
     JOIN list_items li ON l.list_id=li.list_id
  )
SELECT movie_id, count(*) ct
FROM (
   SELECT user_id, movie_id, min(movie_id) OVER (PARTITION BY User_Id) min_movie_id
      , SUM(CASE WHEN movie_id = 1 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) OVER (PARTITION BY user_id) ct
   FROM test_data 
)
WHERE min_movie_id=1 AND movie_id<>1
GROUP BY movie_id
ORDER BY ct desc, movie_id
;
```

Test data expanded back to original tables.  The results are the same as mathguy's.

Comment: Oh... this is not likely to be faster (what with the join, and the aggregation following analytic functions). But it is likely to be correct, and my answer is probably incorrect - assuming a user may have more than one list. You really want to "match" movies by user, not by list... I missed that. Waiting for the OP to clarify the requirement, but I am inclined to believe your answer is the right one.

Comment: Thank you both for your through responses, I tried variations of both and Leigh's seems to get me closer to where I need to be. @mathguy, users CAN have more than one list but only one 'favorite movies' list ... I wasn't sure about using DISTINCT either so thank you for clarifying!

Comment: @mathguy Doing the analytic function avoids having to do multiple scans of “test_data”.  Compare http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/9eecb7d/24801 with http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/9eecb7d/24799 and you'll find that even for this extremely small set of data, doing the analytic is faster.  This would likely become more pronounced as the amount of data increases.  Of course if the system is Memory and/or CPU bound then this may not be true, but often the bottleneck is the disk, so decreasing disk access even at the expense of CPU will frequently produce faster results.

Answer (score 3):

Here is one way to do this.

```
with
     test_data ( user_id, movie_id ) as (
       select 1, 1 from dual union all
       select 2, 1 from dual union all
       select 2, 2 from dual union all
       select 2, 3 from dual union all
       select 3, 2 from dual union all 
       select 3, 3 from dual union all
       select 4, 1 from dual union all
       select 4, 2 from dual union all
       select 4, 9 from dual
     )
--  End of test data (NOT part of the SQL query).
--  Solution (SQL query) begins BELOW THIS LINE. Use your actual table and column names.
select   movie_id, count(*) as ct
from     test_data
where    user_id in ( select user_id from test_data where movie_id = 1 )
  and    movie_id != 1
group by movie_id
order by ct desc, movie_id
;

  MOVIE_ID         CT
---------- ----------
         2          2
         3          1
         9          1

4 rows selected.
```